# C# winforms webbrowser not going to url's asked for

Tags: c#, winforms

I was asked by a friend to develop a winform app to be able to extract data. I figured it would be easy enough - how wrong I was! 
In my winform, I have included a webbrowser control and some buttons. The URL for the webbrowser is `http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/card.sd` and as you can imagine, it is the place to get data for greyhounds. When on the page above, there are a number of links within this area which are specific to a race time. If you click on any of these, it takes you to that race, and its this data that I need to extract. So, my initial thoughts were to get ALL links off the link above, then store them in a list, then just have a button available to take in whatever link it is, and then take the webbrowser to that location. Once there, I can then look to extract the data and store it as needed.

So, in the first instance, I use

```
//url = link above
wb1.Url = new Uri(url);
```

grab the data (which are links for each race on that day)

once I have this, use a further button to go to the specific race

```
wb1.Url = new Uri("http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/card.sd#resultday=2015-01-17&raceid=1344640");
```

then, once there, click another button to capture the data, after which, return to the original link above.

The problem is, it will not go to the location present in the link. BUT, if I click the link manually within the webbrowser, it goes there no problem.

I have looked at the properties of the webbrowser, and these all look fine - although I can't qualify that tbh!

I know if I try to go to the links manually, I can, but if I try to do it through code, it just wont budge. I can only assume I have done something wrong in the code.

Hope some of that makes sense - first posting, so apologies if I made a mess of it. I will provide all code no problem, but cant seem to figure out how to post the code in 'code format'?

//here is the code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Uri _url;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        wb1.Url = new Uri("http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/card.sd");
        wb1.Navigated +=new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(wb1_Navigated);
    }
    classmodules.trackUrl tu;
    private void btnGrabData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        classmodules.utility u = new classmodules.utility();
        rtb1.Text = u.GetWebData("http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/card.sd");
        HtmlDocument doc = wb1.Document;
        string innerText = (((mshtml.HTMLDocument)(doc.DomDocument)).documentElement).outerHTML;
        innerText = Regex.Replace(innerText, @"\r\n?|\n", "");
        rtb1.Text = innerText;

        tu = new classmodules.trackUrl();
        u.splitOLs(ref tu, innerText);
        classmodules.StaticUtils su = new classmodules.StaticUtils();
        su.SerializeObject(tu, typeof(classmodules.trackUrl)).Save(@"d:\dogsUTL.xml");
        classmodules.ExcelProcessor xl = new classmodules.ExcelProcessor();
        xl.createExcel(tu);
    }

    private void wb1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb1 = sender as WebBrowser;
        this.Text = wb1.Url.ToString();
    }

    void wb1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        _url = e.Url;
    }

    private void btnGoBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        goBack();
    }

    private void goBack()
    {
        wb1.Url = new Uri("http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/card.sd");
    }

    private void btnGetRaceData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = wb1.Document;
        string innerText = (((mshtml.HTMLDocument)(doc.DomDocument)).documentElement).outerHTML;
        rtb2.Text = innerText;
    }
```

//###############################

//OK, here is the point where I want to take in the URL and click a button //to instruct the webbrowser to go to that location. I add an initial //counter to 0, and then get the first url from the list, increment the //counter, then when I click the button again, urlNo wil be 1, so then it //tries the second url

```
    int urlNo = 0;
    private void btnUseData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tu.race.Count > urlNo)
        {
            string url = tu.race[urlNo].url;
            wb1.Url = new Uri(url);
            lblUrl.Text = url;
            urlNo++;
        }
        else
        {
            lblUrl.Text = "No More";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read carefully the [Terms and Conditions](http://www.racingpost.com/shared/help_info.sd?cat_id=26&subcat_id=69&headline=TERMSANDCONDITIONS) of the website you're scraping?  While they don't seem to prohibit scraping specifically, they do have an "excessive bandwidth" provision, they're very restrictive about the manner in which you can use the data you obtain, and there's a clause that states they can terminate any account for any reason at their discretion.

Comment: Hi Robert, I am not doing anything untoward. What I am doing can be done manually, by clicking on the link, then getting the data needed, then go to the next link dong the same. So, I am just trying to achieve this by means of code in order to speed up the process. I do not have an account with them. they do have a members section where a paid for subscription will allow you to get data at a premium. The data I want to get is not considered premium.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Navigate(...) method? In theory, the behavior of Navigate and Url is the same, but I can infer that they behave a bit different.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for the response. I did try the navigate method, and it did exactly the same.

Comment: There's almost certainly some sort of automatic navigation busting Javascript code in the page.  Have you looked at that possibility yet?